# the properties given in the function are not visible in its interior

Tags: javascript

I have functions

```
      const change = (nameInput, nameError, nameRegexp) => {
        return () => {
          const val = nameInput.value;
          if (!regexp.nameRegexp.test(val)) {
            error.classList.add('animation');
            error.innerHTML = errorMessage.nameError;
            nameInput.classList.remove('correct');
          } else {
            nameInput.classList.add('correct');
            error.classList.remove('animation');
          }
        }
      }
lastName.addEventListener('change', change(lastName, name, name));
```

The problem is that the `nameError`, `nameRegexp` properties are not visible in the middle of the function.

Why is this happening? How to fix this error?

Comment: You look to be passing the *same* variable, `name`, as `nameError` and `nameRegexp`.

Comment: Well, you're not using them. You're not using `nameError`; you're using `errorMessage.nameError` which is a completely variable. You're not using `nameRegexp`; you're using `regexp.nameRegexp`. I wouldn't be surprised if you were getting errors in the console when you run this as well.

Comment: What do you bet they meant to do `errorMessage[nameError]` and the like?

Comment: **regexp** & **error** seems coming from outer space;   **nameError** & **nameRegexp** are never used in your function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks, the problem is solved

Comment: plus : addEventListener can't send parameter values

Comment: @MrJ the method returns a function, so it is valid in this case.

Comment: remove the parameters from the outer function and put them on the inner function instead